# Gutenberg UI has changed

Tags: admin, block-editor, editor, blog, admin-ui

I'm building a new version of my site offline.
I've exported/imported all my blog posts in and that seems to have worked.

Only thing is, the layout of the Gutenberg editor looks horrible locally.

Is there some config I've missed to make it pretty again?

I've tried creating an editor stylesheet but no luck!

**Old (Good)**
[image: Old]

**New (Bad)**
[image]

Comment: Are you using a different theme? Something is loading an editor stylesheet, and normally the theme is responsible for that.

Comment: Amazing, didn't know that! Thanks, I'll try to overwrite that with something nicer!